# how to add event handler to input via ngAfterViewInit() when input exists in *ngIf="someData"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm hooking up a jQuery on change event handler for test purposes (I know ng2 has an available (change) attribute). In my.component.ts file I can implement the following event handler successfully for a select placed directly below the router-outlet in my.component.html:

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    $('#ddlTest').on('change', function () { alert('jquery change wireup'); });
}
```

However, the real select I need to bind to exists within a div displayed dependent on an underlying component member variable:

```
<div *ngIf="searchMetadata">
   <select id="ddlTest">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

The member variable gets set by the component calling a service and setting the response to the variable. My problem is that it appears that the *ngIf container prevents the ngAfterViewInit event wireup logic from finding the nested select input.  My guess is that ngAfterViewInit looks for the select in the html before the ngIf condition has been actualized. Any idea how I can get the event wireup working while maintaining the ngIf?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another hook.

`ngAfterViewInit` will run before you resolve your service call, so jquery will never find that `#dd1Test` selector.

When you update your `searchMetadata` run this function instead:

```
updateSearchMetadata(value: any): void {
   this.searchMetadata = value;
   setTimeout(() => this.watchJQuerySelectChanges() , 100);
}

watchJQuerySelectChanges(): void {
   if (this.searchMetadata) {
       $('#ddlTest').on('change', function () { alert('jquery change wireup'); });
    }
}
```

Also you should use NgZone ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)) if you want to use angular inside of the `#dd1Test` `onChange` event.

To use NgZone just inject it to the constructor:

```
constructor(public ngZone: NgZone)
```

Then in the callback of the `onChange` event added using jquery just add this:

```
$('#ddlTest').on('change', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.searchMetadata = undefined; // Example to show that angular will see this.
    });
});
```

Update **The best way**

```
<div *ngIf="searchMetadata">
   <select #ddlTest id="ddlTest">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

That will allow us to use the `ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild('ddlTest')
set ddlTest(value: ElementRef) {
   // keep the value if you want it for something.
   $('#ddlTest').on('change', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
           // Do something
           console.log('Hello there!');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks camaron!   I used the input decorator like this: @Input() searchMetadata but change.searchMetadata returns an error: "Property searchMetadata does not exist on type 'SimpleChanges'". What do I need to change with my implementation?  Also, is it enough for me to simply decorate the component member variable searchMetadata  with "@Input()" to enable the ngOnChanges trigger?

Comment: Is there not a more structured way to do this than setTimeout()?

Comment: @user8334943 there you have an update to do this without the setTimeout, remember to accept the answer as the solution if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works.  It's simple and straight forward.  It's hacky but it works.  When addJQueryHook() gets hit, ddlTest above will already be rendered.  If you know a better way then please lmk!

```
<div *ngIf="SearchMetadata">
    <select id="ddlTest">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="addJQueryHook()">
    </div>
</div>
```